# При нажатии на кнопку, срабатывала только один раз

Tags: javascript, click

У меня есть данный код:

```
var list, index;
list = document.getElementsByClassName("save");
console.log(list);
if(list.click()){
    console.log('tested');
}
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
}
```

У меня есть 2 кнопки, которых класс `save`, и при нажатии на любую из них, мне нужно блокировать их обе. Я заблокировать - могу, но не могу поймать клик на кнопку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Syntax) нет метода [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)

Comment: То подскажите, как мне быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function d(){
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.save');
  elements.forEach(element => element.disabled = true)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="save" type="button" value="Кнопка 1" onclick="d()">
  <input class="save" type="button" value="Кнопка 2" onclick="d()">
</div>
```